# Magento 2 preference not working

Tags: magento2, preference

I created a preference, if I try to exit the extended class nothing happens. But if I try it with the following code:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$sample = $bootstrap->getObjectManager()->create('MyParcelNL\Sdk\src\Helper\MyParcelCollection');

\Zend_Debug::dump(get_class($sample));
```

The code is exited??? Anybody an idea why it does not work when using the extended class via the backend in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

```
1)create di.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="vendor\module\Block\Product\ProductsList" />
</config>
2)then create block:
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Block\Product;

class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{

}
```